# Problema al recuperar información desde un puntero

Tags: c++, lista

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase. Tengo que crear una lista doblemente enlazada empleando POO. Creé la clase nodo y la clase lista, pero tengo problemas a la hora de imprimir la lista por pantalla, ya que al acceder a los nodos, imprime basura en lugar de la información previamente introducida en ellos. Este es mi código simplificado y funcional para el ejemplo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class node_c
{   private:
        string flightNumber;

        node_c* next;
        node_c* prev;

    public:
        node_c(void):
            flightNumber("Not asigned"),
            next(nullptr),
            prev(nullptr) {}

        node_c(string flightNumber_, node_c* next_ = nullptr, node_c* prev_ = nullptr){
            assert(flightNumber_.size() > 0);

            flightNumber = flightNumber_;
            next = next_;
            prev = prev_;
        }

        ~node_c(void) {}

        string get_flightNumber(void) const { return flightNumber; }
        node_c* get_next(void) const { return next; }
        node_c* get_prev(void) const { return prev; }

        void set_flightNumber(string flightNumber_) { flightNumber = flightNumber_; }
        void set_next(node_c* next_) { next = next_; }
        void set_prev(node_c* prev_) { prev = prev_; }

        ostream& write(ostream& os) const {   
            os << "Flight Number: " << flightNumber << endl;

            return os;
        }
};

class dll_c
{   private:
        int size;

        node_c* head;
        node_c* tail;

    public:
        dll_c(void):
            size(0),
            head(nullptr),
            tail(nullptr) {}
        
        dll_c(string flightNumber_){
            size = 1;

            node_c nodeHead(flightNumber_);

            head = &nodeHead;
            tail = &nodeHead;
        }

        ~dll_c(void) {}

        node_c* get_head(void) const { return head; }
        node_c* get_tail(void) const { return tail; }

        ostream& write(ostream& os) const
        {   assert(size > 0);
    
            node_c* aux = head;

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                aux->write(os);

                aux = aux->get_next();
            }

            os << endl << endl;

            return os;
        }
};

int main(void)
{   dll_c fullList("AA 0000");

    cout << endl << "FULL LIST: " << endl;

    fullList.write(cout);

    fullList.get_head()->write(cout);

    node_c nodoPrueba("AA 1111");

    nodoPrueba.write(cout);

    return 0;
}
```

Y este es el output en consola:

```
aluXXX@DESKTOP-XXXX:~/Documents/stackOverflow$ ./a.out

FULL LIST:
HHUHpHHyHEHHoH.H',HH=H5
                       HHH+HHHpH5V,HHpHH58,HHoHHoHEH5
```

Al parecer crashea al llamar al método `write()` de la DLL, porque si comentamos esta línea para que quede de la siguiente forma:

```cpp
int main(void)
{   dll_c fullList("AA 0000");

    cout << endl << "FULL LIST: " << endl;

    //fullList.write(cout);

    fullList.get_head()->write(cout);

    node_c nodoPrueba("AA 1111");

    nodoPrueba.write(cout);

    return 0;
}
```

Obtenemos el siguiente output:

```
aluXXX@DESKTOP-XXXX:~/Documents/stackOverflow$ ./a.out

FULL LIST:
Flight Number:
Flight Number: AA 1111
```

Sigue sin imprimir la información del nodo, pero al menos no accede a información errónea.

En la versión original de mi código, la llamada a `fullList.write(cout)` ocasiona un Segmentation Fault, y llamando a `fullList.get_head()->write(cout)` imprimo basura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que `nodeHead` es una variable local y solo vive mientras la función se está ejecutando.

Entonces como `tail` y `head` guardan una referencia a ella, al intentar leer la posición de memoria donde se encontraba `nodeHead` obtienes basura.

Sé 2 soluciones para esto.

- Declara las variables en un lugar de tal forma que su tiempo de vida sea el necesario o el mayor posible, como en la función `main` por ejemplo.
- Usa memoria dinámica. Esta memoria permanece como la dejaste hasta el final del programa.

  Puedes optar por reservar memoria para un solo elemento cada vez o lo que sería más aconsejable, reservar varios bloques de memoria grandes a medida que necesites más. De este modo el programa será más rápido porque va a usar la caché.

  Depende de lo que elijas el procedimiento variará, pero la base es reservar memoria con `new` y liberarla con `delete`:

  ```
  node_c* nodo = new node_c;
  // Así reservas memoria para 10 nodos
  node_c* nodos = new node_c[10];

  ...

  delete nodo;
  delete[] nodos;
  ```

  La regla es que si usaste `new` debes liberar la memoria con `delete` y si usaste `new[]` debes usar `delete[]`.

Comment: @Simeón no problem. Recuerda que estamos en Stackoverflow en español y deberíamos comunicarnos en español. Especialmente en las preguntas y respuestas, sino terminarán cerradas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona. No se me habría ocurrido que ese pudiese ser el problema. Disculpa lo del idioma, me dio un lapsus bilingüe.